# Conditionally set checkbox Values on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, inputcheckboxes, apexinputcheckbox

I am looking to pre-fill/pre-populate a checkbox on my Visualforce page based on a specific picklist condition being met.

In this example, I would like the "ClearingHouse__c" checkbox to be automatically checked on the page if the "Type__c" picklist = "Omega".

Is this possible?

```
 <apex:column headerValue="Type">
   <apex:inputField value="{!a.Condition.Type__c}">
      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="table"/>
   </apex:inputField>
 </apex:column>

 <apex:column headerValue="Clearing House">
   <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.Condition.ClearingHouse__c}"/>
     <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" rerender="table"/>
 </apex:column>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this in both Apex or JavaScript.

As Apex:

```
  <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="table" action="{!a.checkType}" />
```

...

```
public void checkType() {
  if(Condition.Type__c=='Omega') {
    Condition.ClearingHouse__c=true;
  }
}
```

...

*(Note: the code above presumes you have a wrapper class; this method goes in the wrapper.)*

As JavaScript:

...

...

```
<script>
function updateCheckbox(id) {
  var type = document.querySelector(`[data-record-id="${id}"]`);
  var clearinghouse = document.querySelector(`[data-update-id="${id}"]`);
  clearinghouse.checked = type.options[type.selectedIndex].value === 'Omega';
}
</script>
```

...

*((Note: it's been a while since I've written Visualforce+JS, this might need some debugging))*

Side Note:

`apex:actionSupport` must be inside the element it is providing support *for*. This might be part of your problem.

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.Condition.ClearingHouse__c}">
  <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" rerender="table"/>
</apex:inputCheckbox>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback sfdcfox.  How does the javascript function know how to reference the correct "clearinghouse" field in Salesforce?

Comment: Also, the Apex/VF approach does not seem to be working and the inputcheckbox remains unchecked.  I do have a wrapper class and here is the method                                                             
`public pagereference checkType() {
        
        if(Condition.Type__c == 'Omega') {
      
            Condition.Clearinghouse__c=TRUE;
    }
        return null;
 } `

Comment: Visualforce markup: `<apex:column headerValue="Type" >
                    <apex:inputField value="{!a.Condition.Type__c}">
                         <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="table"/>
                    </apex:inputField>
                </apex:column>
                
                <apex:column headerValue="Clearing House">
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.Condition.Clearinghouse__c}"/>
                     <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" rerender="table" action="{!checkType}"/>
                </apex:column>`